# Custom position divs inside of html file?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for the best strategy to custom position divs inside of an HTML file?

Trying to put together a dashboard with graphs and other inputs but I'm looking for these visuals to be custom placed around the center image. So far I've just been able to place them inside of a pre-determined grid.

[image: example]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of this type of styling, however there is something you could try:

```
.div1{ //the class of your div
    postion: absolute;
    top: 25%; //this is the margin percentage from the top
    left: 60%; //this is the margin percentage from the left
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This is not a realy solid solution, but it will place the divs wherever you want them on the page relative to the top and left.

Comment: Is there a better (or more recommended) way of achieving this?